# Configuring network settings in Google TV emulator

Tags: android, google-tv

Can anyone please help me in configuring proxy settings on my google tv emulator? In other Android emulators,we have an option to set the proxy and port in the Network settings. Couldn't find a similar one in Google TV emulator.
I am totally stuck at this part. Don't know how to configure network settings in GTV emulator.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the network settings by including specific parameters when you run the emulator.  These parameters are described at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

HTTP proxy settings are available.